# Can anyone tell me more about this measure of asymmetry

Tags: reference-request

I have a measure of asymmetry (Q ranging from $-1$ to $1$) between two paired variables (x,y; both positive integers) and would like to know more about where this equation comes from, where it's been applied and what math one could do with it. Sorry for this vague question and Thank you!

Q = $\frac{x-y}{x+y}$

Comment: Statistical_dispersion and Quartile Co-efficient of dispersion (both from wikipedia) will help you a lot.

Comment: Your Q is Quartile co-efficient of dispersion

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking into this now!